# List yearly, monthly, quarterly, biweekly dates interval in a column through excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the table below.

[image]

In the first column, I placed the periods (or the number of instances; it works like an ID in this table). The table is named "LoanSchedule". 
$B$20 stores a date. In this case, I entered February 20, 2020.
I have this formula in Column 2 to list the consecutive monthly date after $B$20. 
$B$18 stores the number of times payment is made in a year

```
=IF(AND([@[Payment Period]]<>"",$B$20<>"--"),IF($B$18=12,EOMONTH($B$20,ROW([@[Payment Period]])-ROW(LoanSchedule[[#Headers],[Payment Period]])-1)+DAY($B$20),"--"))
```

It works well if payment is monthly or  $B$18 = 12. 
How can I modify the formula if Payment periods will be quarterly(4x year), yearly, or biweekly (26weeks), and list the corresponding months?

For example if I choose quarterly & $B$20 stays the same, the dates that will be displayed on the second column will be May 20, 2020; August 20, 2020, November 20, 2020, February 20, 2021, etc. if Biweekly, every 2 weeks. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can perhaps try a formula like `=DATE(YEAR($B$20),MONTH($B$20)+([@[Payment Period]]*(12/$B$18)),DAY($B$20))` for handling cases more than a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to translate the entries in B18 (number of pmts per year), and the payment period, into the number of months or days to add to the original date.

I translated {1,4,12} using a lookup table with vlookup, handling 26 separately for the 14 day interval (2 weeks).

*I chose this method because merely dividing `12/$B$18` would require a more complex formula should the result of the division not be an integer, since payments would then not be at monthly intervals*

```
=IF($B$18=26,$B$20+14*[@[Payment Period]],
EDATE($B$20,VLOOKUP($B$18,{1,12;4,3;12,1},2,FALSE)*[@[Payment Period]]))
```

#### B18 = 12

[image]

#### B18=4

[image]

#### B18=26

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm. I will study the formula and understand how it works. I`m just learning to use EDATE. Thanks.